# Where to find Java built-in function's definition/mechanism?

Tags: java

For example, Java String class have the function `split()`, we developers know how to call it (refer to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)) but we don't know how its going to process the input? I want to know the mechanism/algorithm of the code instead of knowing what parameter should I put. Can you tell me where to find the code block defined by Java? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look on open JDK

Comment: This is what you're looking for http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

Comment: Just look in the source code.

Comment: thank you guys! awesome! =)